# set not updating MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am student and am learning about full-stack JavaScript development. I am using a L[inkedIn course](https://www.linkedin.com/learning/react-creating-and-hosting-a-full-stack-site/react-for-full-stack-solutions?u=76115650) where you write a blog with "upvoting" functionality. When I attempt to update the MongoDB with a new "upvote count" the value of 0 is replaced with null. The example code (which appears to be working the course) also seems to have a flaw. This is the code:

```
'$set': {
upvotes: articleInfo.upvotes + 1,
},
```

The field is called upvote in the database and I saw from [the MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) that this may be the problem. However, when I altered the code to be

```
'$set': {
upvote: articleInfo.upvote + 1,
},
```

it had no impact. 
Any thoughts?

I have also confirmed that the articleInfo constant is correct as it works properly with similarly written comment functionality.

Comment: There are two differences between the snippets.  Both `upvotes` became `upvote`.  Have you confirmed that the property on the `articleInfo` is indeed `upvote` and not `upvotes`?

Comment: `articleInfo.upvotes + 1` is evaluated in the client before sending the update to the mongod server, so what the server sees in `'$set:{ upvotes: null }` use `$inc` operator as suggested by @Đĵ ΝιΓΞΗΛψΚ

Answer (score 0):

usually you increment a number of a field in mongodb like this:

```java
db.collection.updateOne(
    {
        _id: ObjectId("5ea3c8124d9d030dc05074e4")
    },
    {
        $inc: { upvote: 1 }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your thoughts and help. The database was pretty messed up after I misnamed one of the fields (update, instead of updates) and then tried to push data to the wrong field. I wound up creating a new database with a correctly named field and then everything worked as it should.